# Run synchronous library function asynchronously

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using a library that runs sync and I want to wrap it in a thread or something like in Java. Do I need to make a new asyn function or is there something like asynchronous.run(...) in Dart/Flutter?

Comment: and cant you make your own version of `asynchronous.run` ? seems simple

Comment: I could, but I wanted to know if there is something premade for this

Comment: What if I told you it is doing exactly the same thing - calls callback passed as argument in async block. 3 lines of code maybe?